# Use a json file in my react-native project

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a json file in my react-native project how do I access it in one of my components?

The structure of the project

It has index.js and App on the same level
Then it has components on the next level
In components it has databases and Main.js
In databases it has database.json

I want to use information held in database.json inside Main.js, I can also change the file structure not sure what is the best way to do this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just require your JSON file like any regular javascript file.

```
let data = require('../../database.json')
```